# How do you express "additional complexity"?

Tags: computational-complexity

Let's say I have two algorithms, one of which is less efficient in the sense that the complexity in the $\mathcal{O}$ notation has an additional factor $n$ (so for example, one is $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ while the other is only $\mathcal{O}(n)$.

So how can I express the difference between these two algorithms, *not knowing their overall complexity*? For example, I may know that $A_1$ and $A_2$ are built using a common building block, but that $A_1$ does the main computation $n$ times while $A_2$ only does it once. Can I say $A_1$ is more complex than $A_2$ by $\mathcal{O}(n)$?

Example:

$A_1$:

```
for i = 1 : n
    do_something_with_unknown_constant_complexity(...);
end
```

$A_2$:

```
do_something_with_unknown_constant_complexity(...);
```

Comment: With your first sentence, do you mean to say that $\mathcal{O}(\exp(n))$ equals $\mathcal{O}(n\exp(n))$? I agree with the second sentence, but I want to express by how much $A_1$ is better than $A_2$.

Comment: Now you say it, I doubt whether my first sentence is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The premise that an $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ function is more complex
than an $\mathcal{O}(n)$ function is not quite right.
The big-$\mathcal{O}$ notation acts more like an *upper bound*
than like an exact equation.

For example, $f(n) = n$ is $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$.
Usually we'd say it's $\mathcal{O}(n)$, 
but it's certainly $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ too;
in fact $\mathcal{O}(n)$ implies $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$.

But you would never want to say that $f(n) = n$ is $\mathcal{O}(n)$
as complex as $g(n) = 2n$, merely because the statements
"$f(n) = n$ is $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$" and "$g(n) = 2n$ is $\mathcal{O}(n)$"
happen to be true.

If you can show that the ratio $\dfrac{A_1(n)}{A_2(n)}$
is $\mathcal{O}(n)$, then I think it is fine to say that
$A_1$ is more complex than $A_2$ by *at most* a factor of $\mathcal{O}(n)$.
In the example you describe, however, you might be able to prove
that $\dfrac{A_1(n)}{A_2(n)}$ is $\Theta(n)$, which is a stronger
condition, and lets you say that
$A_1$ is more complex than $A_2$ by a factor of $\Theta(n)$.